# How to get SharePoint 2010 controls in toolbox

Tags: sharepoint-2010

My application uses Visual Studio 2010 to develop an application in SharePoint 2010. I created a visual webpart and added a `<SharePoint:SPCalendarView ID="EventsCalendar1" width="100%" runat="server"></SharePoint:SPCalendarView>` I also found that there are many other controls which appears in intellisense. How can I add these controls to the toolbox? Is there any documentation available on how to use these controls?